# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript is only being called once in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a datatable that contains records I have gotten from a database. When the page loads i want to go through each record and submit the values to a JavaScript function that will display them to the page however, it only works for the first record in the table. If anyone has a way to fix this or a better way to do what i am aiming to do it will be appreciated.

My code behind:

```
foreach(DataRow row in tlds.Rows) {
    TLDid = Convert.ToInt32(row["tldID"]);
    tldName = row["tldName"].ToString();
    date = row["releaseDate"].ToString();
    price = Convert.ToDouble(row["price"]);
    tags = row["tags"].ToString();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "tld", "addTLD('" + TLDid + "','" + tldName + "','" + date + "','" + price + "')", true);
}
```

My js function:

```
function addTLD(tldID, tldName, releaseDate, price) {
    $('<tr><td>' + tldName + '</td><td>' + releaseDate + '</td><td>' + price + '</tr>').insertAfter('tr');
}
```

Comment: Use a GridView. Much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET server-side Table control and then dynamically add rows and for each row add required cells like the code below

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Table ID="myTable" runat="server" Width="100%"> 
</asp:Table>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
    foreach (DataRow row in tlds.Rows)
                {
                    date = row["releaseDate"].ToString();
                    price = Convert.ToDouble(row["price"]);
                    tags = row["tags"].ToString();

                     TableRow row = new TableRow();

                     TableCell TLIdCell= new TableCell();
                     TLIdCell.Text = Convert.ToInt32(row["tldID"]);
                     row.Cells.Add(TLIdCell);

                      TableCell tldNameCell = new TableCell();
                      tldNameCell .Text = Convert.ToString(row["tldName"]);
                      row.Cells.Add(tldNameCell);

                     //Similarly add code for date, price and tags cells

                      // Finally add row to table rows collection
                      myTable.Rows.Add(row);
                }
```